# How do I store voicemail password on WP8?

Tags: 8.0, voicemail, password

I would like to store my voicemail password on Windows Phone 8. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean for Visual Voicemail? If it isn't storing it you need to call AT&T

Comment: This is on Verizon Wireless. Just plain voicemail.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: Seems like on Android I was able to put in a contact that included voicemail number and password.

Comment: You might be able to do something like that, have it dial your voicemail, insert some pauses, then dial in the password. I've done stuff like this for speed dial on different systems before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YESSS!!!  IT IS POSSIBLE.  here is my simple cheat for the voicemail p/w dilemma on my WP8... Without creating a contact in your phone book.  The commas wouldn't save for me after trying the above. So I used a lower case letter p.  AND yes I know WP8 limits the input in the phone settings area SO- The trick is to  type it into a text anywhere else-
For example -
*86pp1234567 (you can use either one or two p's)

Then highlight and copy it.

Then go back to the settings and paste it in place of the default voicemail #.

Comment: Awesome work-around.  Works perfectly for me.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes ... it absolutely does.
Nokia Icon (Lumia 929).
Created the *86pnnnn in a text message window, copied to clipboard, then pasted into the non-default text box in the Voice Mail Settings.
Then called VoiceMail and password was entered!
Excellent!
I had previously created Voice Mail contact - which also works.

Answer (score 5):

In theory you should be able to save your VM pin in the Dialer settings. There is an option to turn OFF the default voicemail number and enter in your own. (For Verizon you would enter *86,0000# where 0000 is your pin, the comma can be accessed by pressing and holding down the "." key)

This worked on my WP7 phone (HTC Trophy) and I've tried several times on my HTC Windows 8X but continue to recieve an error message ("We're having trouble saving your voicemail number right now. Please try again later").  Don't know if it's a Verizon, Microsoft or HTC issue and have been unable to find anything about it on the web.

**UPDATE**

This appears to be a permanent limitation/feature of WP8. According to a [Microsoft MVP](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wppersonal/program-a-pin-into-voicemail-call-86/7ae17a08-cf19-4dbd-a8f6-5dfc01358cd2), overriding the VoiceMail number to include your PIN is a security issue.

> The system doesn't let you intentionally override security for
>   voicemail. You can do this for numbers stored in your normal contact
>   list, but you can't concatenate your password to the voicemail number.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with error message when trying to change the standard VM number.  I created a new contact called "Auto Voicemail" with the *86,0000# and use that if I need to be hands free.

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to know your Voicemail number. You can go to the website of your carrier, or simply call.

Then, you would need to use the copy/paste method used on Cellenbow's answer.

Type the number in a normal text box, then highlight and copy, go to the Voicemail input box. And paste.

You would need to use either , (comma) or p (pause). Comma can be accessible from the . (Dot) key in the Voicemail, hold on the dot key, then you can choose the comma.

You might need one or two commas or pauses. It depends on how your voicemail carrier settings. I would recommend calling voicemail, and having a stopwatch or anything similar, and count how many seconds are there from the time your call get answered, untill they require you for PIN entry. And every comma/pause is worth 3-5. So you might need to count for that. But don't use too many, because then your call will be dropped for timeout.

Also, some carriers will require you to enter your PIN then press the # (pound) key. If that is the case, then you will need to include that.

Think of it as if you are telling the phone what to enter in the keypad when u call someone, they created this method so you can store phone numbers with extensions to be autodialed.

Finally, WP8.1 might be just fine with entering the comma and the PIN right away, and it will save it without any issues. (I have tested it)

I know this question was asked a long while ago, but I hope this was helpful and brief. (It is self-explanatory)